# Exporting WooCommerce Bookable Product Data

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

We are redesigning a clients WordPress/WooCommerce store and need to migrate their entire WooCommerce product database from the existing site. Due to bugs in the existing site a clone is out of the question but when migrating the products we are only able to migrate the physical products and not all of the associated resources and cost variables.

Given it takes 10 to 15 minutes to create all the the variables for each product and there are 40 products this is going to take a lot of time.

Does anyone know a plugin/method for doing this?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a plugin, tool, software library, tutorial, book, or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. If you cannot find a resource that does what you want it to, then you'll need to write your own.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about any free plugin, but there is a great plugin for exporting/importing anything related to WordPress. You can try [WP All Export](http://www.wpallimport.com/export/) and [WP All Import](http://www.wpallimport.com/) with WooCommerce addon. You can also [test drive](http://www.wpallimport.com/try/) before buying it.

Comment: Please do not answer low quality questions that do not meet SO community guidelines.  You only encourage that kind of behavior.